# WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80070241 Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file

Tags: ubuntu, runtime-error, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

> Installing, this may take a few minutes... WslRegisterDistribution
> failed with error: 0x80070241 Error: 0x80070241 Windows cannot verify
> the digital signature for this file. A recent hardware or software
> change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or
> damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source.
>
> Press any key to continue...

This is the output i'm getting when running Ubuntu20.04 .
I install Ubuntu from Microsoft store.
I'm working on Win10 pro and OS Version is "10.0.19041 N/A Build 19041"

I've tried :

1. making sure Hyper-V is on and the WSL feature is on
2. restart LXSSManager in services
3. checking the bios that virtualization on.
4. uninstalling and installing again ubuntu .

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by uninstalling wsl_update_x64 Install package. After installing it again i got different error , the error was 0x80070002 , the fix for that error , which was setting the wsl to version 1 (wsl --set-default-version 1) , help run the ubuntu without errors.

Comment: This isn't really a fix but a workaround - what if you need exactly ver. 2 ?

Comment: I have fixed your exact issue just now by running sfc /scannow as Administrator in CMD and rebooting my PC - seems like several blackouts have messed up some system files.

Comment: I had the same issue and got rid of it  by reinitializing my Windows using the online installation instead of the local installation. This way I am able to use WSL2